# Equality of two complex series

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to either prove or disprove the following:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} nz^n = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2z^{2n}$$ for all complex numbers satisfying $|z| < 1$.

I mean, if we could somehow remove the $n$ and $n^2$ part we'd get two geometric series which converge because $|z| < 1$, but the $n$-dependence makes me think this is not the way to approach it.

If I plug the sums into wolfram alpha they are different, but I have no idea how to find either of the sums of the two series due to the $n$ multipliers. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m}nz^n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{z\left(mz^{m+1}-(m+1)z^m+1\right)}{(z-1)^2}$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m}n^2z^{2n}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{z^2(-1-z^2+z^{2m}(1+z^2+m(2+m-2(1+m)z^2+mz^4)))}{(z^2-1)^3}$$

Comment: Where did you even get that stuff from? I've never seen anything like that before.
Edit: Is it partial sum formulas?

Comment: You can work out sums that are to an undefinite limit

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What are the derivatives of each power series at $0$?

Comment: I did that for the first one and got the sum. For the second one I wasn't sure how to derive the sum without having it in terms of $n$.

Comment: Mmm ... You're missing something very easy.

Comment: Just gimme a minute to get on the PC and I'll type up my workings so far, then you can maybe help me from there! Watch this space for an edit

Comment: Ok well I cant edit haha. Heres what I did. $$\frac{d}{dz} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = \frac{d}{dz}\left( \frac{1}{1-z}\right)$$ $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} nz^n= \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$ Then, I tried to do the same method for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2z^{2n}$, where I started with just $z^{2n}$, took the derivative, etc, but I was not sure how to simplify the RHS, nor did I even know what the original sum of $z^{2n}$ was. Edit: Perhaps the sum of $\displaystyle z^{2n} = \frac{1}{1-z^2}$?

Comment: No need for any of that. Call the first power series $f(z),$ the second one $g(z).$  Evaluate $ f'(0), g'(0).$